# Ajax Call Hangs Browser - I don't care about the response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How do I abort an Ajax call if I don't really care for the response as I don't want to hang the browser?

The situation is I have an ajax call that could trigger the server sending over a 1000 emails in some cases. 99% of the time it is only a few or tens of emails.
So with the 1000 email ajax call, the browser waits sometimes 5 minutes before it gets the success message, thus the user has to wait.

I have tried setting a timeout, but this still hangs. I'd like to wait about 20 seconds and then abort waiting for the response.

```
var request = jQuery.ajax({
        type: "post",url: "admin-ajax.php",
        data: { 
            action: 'send_email', 
            emailHTMLMessage: tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent(),             
            _ajax_nonce: '<?php echo $nonce; ?>' 
        },
        timeout: 20000, //Set your timeout value
        success: function(html){ //so, if data is retrieved, store it in html
            window.scrollTo(0,0);
            sendResults(html);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if(textStatus==="timeout") {  
                <... I'd redirect to another html page here....> 
            } else {
                alert("Another error was returned"); //Handle other error type
            }
        }
}); //close jQuery.ajax
```

I have tried request.abort() but this kills it immediately and the server never gets the send_email message.

How can I quietly ignore the response after 20secs while the server carries on doing it's thing?

Comment: Ajax call is asynchronous, so your browser is not blocked and there is no need to wait for anything. YOu can put empty function for success. Even if you go away in your browser, you server script has been launched and can do its job until the end, using the `ignore_user_abort` and a good `set_time_limit` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this post there are afew ways to keet the script running after the http request ends:

[Can a PHP script start another PHP script and exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447817/can-a-php-script-start-another-php-script-and-exit)

So you can leave your email script running on the server.

If you want to know the status you could make your email script update to a mysql table how many emails are sent and check with an ajax request the count from the mysql table.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending 1000 emails, that call is going to contain some overhead no matter what you do.  You are also going to have to wait until all the information is sent to the server before you want to allow the user to leave the page as well.

My suggestion would be to change the server code to respond as soon as the server gets their request.  That way the client isn't waiting on the server to finish sending the entire batch, rather just waiting for their request to be received by the server.

Comment: The server does the heavy lifting here, all the Ajax call does is send the email contents, and I have tried responding before the mass email send, eg, in the PHP:


            '// Report Back all is ok!
            echo 'emailSuccess';

            // Do the sending....
            $this->send_newsletter($email_data, $subscribers); 

        }
        else {
            echo 'Fail';
        }
        die();'

Comment: But instead of sending the emails immediately you could also store them in a database and use a cron job to send them in batches. Also note that the PHP `mail()` function is not the best tool for sending lots of emails.

Answer (score 0):

Just post without using the success, timeout or error callbacks.

You might want to try creating a new get request for each email:

```
for(i = 0; i<1000; i++){

    var request = $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "admin-ajax.php",
        data: {'i':'nada'}
    });

};
```

In this case, I used a for loop, but you could also use an array of emails:

```
var emails = new Array(1000);

$.each(emails, function(){

    var request = $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url : "admin-ajax.php",
        data: {'i':'nada'}

    });

});
```

Comment: I've tried this, but the browser still hangs until all the emails are sent on the server.