# Browser Get hange when send mass mails in php

Tags: php, email

I am sending Mass mail in PHP using the third party tool "PHP List".When as I am running the PHP list "process_queue.php" from my system within Iframe.Thehe browser continuously loading.also the browser get hanged.

What I need after run that "process_queue.php" script, I just want to show the static output "mail processing" notification instead of browser get loading for long time.

Could you please advice?

Comment: look at this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436575/can-a-php-script-trick-the-browser-into-thinking-the-http-request-is-over

Answer (score 1):

Rather than executing it through HTTP, consider using the provided [command-line script](http://docs.phplist.com/CommandLineScriptInfo) or executing a [cron job](http://docs.phplist.com/SetupCronJob).

See [the documentation](http://docs.phplist.com/ProcessQueueInfo) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to send request to PHP for each email and then can show progress on the page as well.