# how to print in php before the execution

Tags: php, html, flush

I have a form which when submitted, calls a php page (sample.php)

my php page does a lot of execution, which takes around 5 mins of time. i am also printing "Executed!" on my sample.php page.

This Executed gets printed.. only after it has executed everything ( 5mins).

I want my php page to print "Executed" before it does all the processing.

How shuld i go about this?

Comment: print at the start of the page

Comment: and it should be something like execution in progress or progress bar maybe as otherwise you are lying :)

Comment: @Bojan well.. i was just giving an example above..

Comment: @user1370510 that does not work.. it still waits..

Comment: can you post some sample code please

Comment: Sounds like the job should go into a queue and be handled by a worker asynchronously in the background. Leaving a page loading for 5 minutes is a terrible idea.

Comment: @deceze have a good point, maybe use ajax for handling time consuming process.

Comment: Take a look at this question: Can a PHP script trick the browser into thinking the HTTP request is over? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436575/can-a-php-script-trick-the-browser-into-thinking-the-http-request-is-over

Answer (score 0):

There have been several solutions posted that use `ignore_user_abort()` and `flush()` to continue background work after a page has been delivered to the client. You should start reading the documentation on [connection handling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php) on the php web site

However, if you ask for a stable solution, I would design your application in a way that 'sample.php' (the form action) will just recieve a job, adds it to a queue (maybe a database table) and reports that the job has been added. Where another process runs in background (maybe per cron or whatever) and runs the jobs itself. Also I would create a page like 'progress.php' where the progress of a job can be viewed. The response could be json or something like this, so that it can be easily integrated into other pages or used as data feed for the javascript progress bar you've been asked for.